# What type of PDE are Navier-Stokes equations, and Schrödinger equation?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, differential-equations, navier-stokes

What type of PDE are [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations), and [Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)?

I mean, are they [parabolic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_partial_differential_equation), [hyperbolic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_equation), [elliptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation) PDEs?

Comment: With the Schrödinger equation it depends on the Hamiltonian you supply.

Comment: With the Navier-Stokes equations it depends on the Mach number. Subsonic flows are elliptic, supersonic flows are parabolic.

Comment: What's the motivation behind the question? I'm just curious.

Comment: @user12345 I really don't know much about PDEs theory, but I was wondering this because I use those PDEs as a physics student, so I thought it was important to know something like this, I mean a really basic thing. Also, the answer of this question is not clear in usual undergraduate physics books. Of course, if you know some books that treat this, please tell me.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't offer any assistance because I myself, (also a physics student) have never come across these properties. Do they have a physical interpretation or just a mathematical one?

Comment: Well, I understand that depending of the type of PDE, there are specific boundary conditions to satisfy the uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: @user12345 For the Navier-Stokes equations, there is a physical significance. (I cannot speak for the Schrodinger equations) For instance in supersonic flow, disturbances do not travel upstream. This is nice if you are trying to use a [Pitot tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_tube) in the flow because it will not strongly affect what you are trying to measure. I am currently doing subsonic research and it is sometimes extremely difficult to make sure that any measurement probes are not changing the flow field.

Comment: One of my colleagues spent the last month or so trying to figure out why the wake behind a cylindrical roughness element on a flat plate was at an angle with the freestream direction. As it turns out, the [hot-wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemometer#Hot-wire_anemometers) holder that he was using had too much blockage and was influencing the flow upstream of the hot-wire. This is entirely a result of the Navier-Stokes equations being elliptic for subsonic flows.

Comment: @user2018790 Nice!

Comment: realted: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75363/226902

Answer (score 2):

Classification into parabolic, elliptic and hyperbolic equations applies to the [*second order linear partial differential equations with constant coefficients*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Linear_equations_of_second_order). That is, it applies to the equations that are:

- linear
- second order
- have constant coefficients

Thus one particle non-relativistic time-dependent Schrödinger equation with no external potential or magnetic field can be classified as parabolic (although with complex coefficients - its real-coefficients equivalent is the diffusion equation.) In time-independent case in more than one dimension, Schrödinger equation is elliptic.

Navier-Stokes equation is non-linear, and hence does not fit this classification.

Answer (score 1):

Time-dependent Schrodinger equation is an elliptic PDE if the Hamiltonian is time-independent.