# relation between Schrodinger equation and wave equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, optics

I have always been confused by the relationship between the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_and_experimental_justification_for_the_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) and the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation).

$$ i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2+ U \psi  \hspace{0.25in}\text{-vs-}\hspace{0.25in}\nabla^2 E = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial^2 t} $$

Because of the first derivative, the Schrödinger equation looks more like the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation).

Some derivations of the Schrodinger equation start from [wave-particle duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality) for light and argue that matter should also exhibit this phenomenon.

In some notes by [Fermi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226243818), it was derived by comparing the [Fermat least time principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle) $\delta \int n \;ds = 0 $ and Maupertuis [least action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) $\delta \int 2T(t) \; dt = 0 $.

Was this ever clarified?  How can we see the idea of a matter-wave more quantitatively?

---

To summarize, I am trying to understand why the Electromagnetic wave equation is hyperbolic while the Schrodinger equation is parabolic.

Comment: For a connection between Schr. eq. and Klein-Gordon eq, see e.g. A. Zee, _QFT in a Nutshell,_ Chap. III.5, and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32383/2451) Phys.SE post plus links therein.

Answer (score 7):

To see the idea of a matter-wave more quantitatively and to relate it to the electrocmagnetic fields, it can be helpful to consider a beam propagating in one dimension.  For example, a laser (or other coherent light source) propagating down some path. In this scenario, you can treat the transverse laplacian and the z-derivatives (z being the direction of propagation) independently.

The wave equation for EM waves is:

$$\hspace{0.25in}\nabla^2 E = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial^2 t} $$

this differential equation has plane wave solutions, so without loss of generality you can can examine a field of the form:

$$E(\vec{r}) = A(\vec{r}) e^{i\omega t+ik_0t}$$

$$\nabla^2 \vec{E} = \partial_{xx} \vec{E} + \partial_{yy}\vec{E} + \partial_{zz}\vec{E}$$

$$\nabla^2 \vec{E}= e^{i\omega t + ik_0 z} \partial_{xx} A(\vec{r}) + e^{i\omega t + ik_0 z} \partial_{yy} A(\vec{r}) + \partial_{zz}A(\vec{r})e^{i\omega t + ik_0z}$$

$$
 e^{i\omega t +ik_0z} \nabla^2 A(\vec{r}) + 2ik_0 e^{i\omega t +ik_0z}\partial_z A(\vec{r} ) - k_0^2 e^{i\omega t +ik_0z} A(\vec{r})
$$

The wave equation can then be written as:
$$
e^{i\omega t +ik_0z}\nabla^2 A(\vec{r}) + 2ik_0 e^{i\omega t +ik_0z} \partial_z A(\vec{r} ) - k_0^2 e^{i\omega t +ik_0z} A(\vec{r}) + \frac{\omega^2 n^2}{c^2}A(\vec{r}) e^{i\omega t +ik_0z} = 0
$$
By dropping the common exponent, this can be simplified to:
$$
\nabla^2 A(\vec{r}) + 2ik_0 \partial_z A(\vec{r} ) - k_0^2  A(\vec{r}) + \frac{\omega^2 n^2}{c^2}A(\vec{r})  = 0
$$

And define the transverse laplacian to be

$$ \nabla^2_\perp = \nabla^2 - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$$

And by making the slowly varying envelope approximation:

$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}A(\vec{r}) \ll k_0 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}A(\vec{r}) \ll k_0^2A(\vec{r}) $$

Also use the dispersion relation:
$$
k_0 = \frac{n\omega}{c}
$$

The wave equation can then be written as:

$$ i\frac{\partial A(\vec{r})}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2k_0}\nabla_\perp^2 A(\vec{r})$$ which is in the same form as the Schroedinger equation in the absence of an external potential *with the exception* that instead of varying with time $t$, it varies with position along the axial direction, $z$.

Comment: OK.  [Slowly varying envelope approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_envelope_approximation) turns this [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation) PDE into a [parabolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_partial_differential_equation) one.

Comment: @johnmangual Yes.