# Is every function that satisfies classical wave equation, represent a wave?

Tags: waves

I'm studying about the waves and the classical wave equation where I'm searching  out the methods to check whether a function represents a wave or not, and I come up with this question.

Comment: Possibly related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75363/how-is-the-schroedinger-equation-a-wave-equation

Comment: Every function that satisfies the classical wave equation is a wave.

Answer (score 0):

Most functions can be expressed as a sum of sines and cosines (waves)  though the use of a [Fourrier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) and are therefore wave like(a sum of waves is a wave).

[So when exactly can we apply a Fourrier Transform ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3326542/59383)

> Well there are 3 conditions for a Fourier Series of a function to be
> exist: 1. It has to be periodic. 2. It must be single valued,
> continuous.it can have finite number of finite discontinuities. 3. It
> must have only a finite number of Maxima and minima within the period.
> 4. The Integral over one period of |f(X)| must converge. Each of them have Analytical proofs but let's discuss them using analogy.

Comment: This may be true, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I'm replying to the concern stated as "I'm searching out the methods to check whether a function represents a wave or not". If the method  can be fourrier transformed, it represents a wave

Comment: will you also give answer to the direct question,"Is every function that satisfies classical wave equation, represent a wave?"

Comment: Condition #1 kills your argument.   Not every wave is periodic.

Comment: I believe you'd have to define what a wave is, cause if a wave can be anything then we are in trouble.

Comment: from wiki, wave equation : "The basic wave equation is a linear differential equation and so it will adhere to the superposition principle. This means that the net displacement caused by two or more waves is the sum of the displacements which would have been caused by each wave individually. In addition, the behavior of a wave can be analyzed by breaking up the wave into components, e.g. the Fourier transform breaks up a wave into sinusoidal components. "